# Xamarin Android specific Ioc in MvvmCross constructor issue

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

**tldr: Is there any way I can choose which constructor to use when I register a type?**

I have followed the instructions to create a platform specific inversion of control as outlined in [Inversion of control](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc).

> In your core project, you can declare an interface and you can use
>   that interface in your classes there ...
>
> In each UI project, you can then declare the platform-specific
>   implementation ...
>
> You can then register these implementations in each of the
>   platform-specific Setup files - e.g. you could override
>   MvxSetup.InitializeFirstChance

So in my core project I have defined the following interface

```
public interface IJob
    {
        void AddAction(Action action);

    }
```

In my Android project I have implemented the interface as follows

```
public class CustomJob: Job, IJob
{
    private Action _action;

    public CustomJob(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public CustomJob() : base(new Params
    (Jobs.Priority.MID
    ).RequireNetwork().Persist())
    {
        //_action = action;
    }

    public override void OnAdded()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCancel(int p0, Throwable p1)
    {
    }

    public override void OnRun()
    {
        _action.Invoke();
    }

    protected override RetryConstraint ShouldReRunOnThrowable(Throwable p0, int p1, int p2)
    {
        return RetryConstraint.Cancel;
    }

    public void AddAction(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }
}
```

And I overrode the implementation of `InitializeFirstChance` in Setup.cs

```
 protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
        {
            Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<IJob, CustomJob>();
            base.InitializeFirstChance();
        }
```

However, I get the following stacktrace at runtime

> {MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve
>   parameter for parameter javaReference of type IntPtr when creating
>   CustomJob. You may pass it as an argument   at
>   MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type,
>   System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] arguments)
>   [0x0005a] in
>   C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:648    at
>   MvvmCross.IoC.MvxIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] arguments)
>   [0x00031] in
>   C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\IoC\MvxIoCContainer.cs:413

Is there any way I can choose which constructor to use when I register a type? Thank you.

Comment: Which constructor is it that you want? By default most IoC containers choose the one with most parameters.

Comment: From the error message it looks like it is unable to resolve `IntPtr` when constructing `CustomJob` object graph

Comment: I would like to use the parameterless one: public CustomJob()

Comment: Ok. Looking at it another way, Why have the other constructor? That is not clear from the question in its current state.

Comment: It's a class from a Java Bindings project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't choose which constructor the Mvx's IoC engine will choose.

So one way is to make another class that implements your `IJob` that has a reference to `Job` internally and in the implementation of the class you pass the action to the `Job` implementation.

```cs
public class JobHandler : IJob
{
    private Job _customJob;

    public JobHandler()
    {
        this._customJob = new CustomJob();
    }

    public void AddAction(Action action)
    {
        this._customJob.AddAction(action);
    }
}
```

If you want you can do an `IJobHandler` that inherits `IJob` so that you can use that interface for the `JobHandler` implementations and the `IJob` for you actual `Job`

---

Another way is to add stub parameters to the parameterless constructor so that it takes more parameters than the other and gets elected by the IoC engine (I'm not entirely sure that it would work, but I think so). But it is a bit messy.

---

Another way is you to tell the IoC engine how you want to construct your `IJob`:

```cs
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<IJob>(() => new CustomJob());
```

HIH